# How to display more than one cell in detailed table view when a cell is clicked on Master table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, master-detail

I am working on a master detail application. Here the master table view contains a list and a add button . When I click on add button ,it asks the user to enter the following information

```
   Name:
   Month entered:
```

For example If I  enter the following:

```
   Name: John
   Month entered: January
```

Now in the Master Table view, the first row will be displayed as:

```
     Name: John
     Month entered:January
```

and when the user click on this row , the detail view will be displayed as:

```
Name: John
Month's entered so far:January
```

If I press the add button again and entered the same name and month as february,then the first row on master view will be :

```
Name:John
Month entered:February
```

and the detail view would be having two cells as follows:

```
Name:John
Month's entered so far:January
---------------
Name:John
Month's entered so far:February
```

The problem  is ,in the detail view I am unable to get two cells even though I add two months.The two cells are displaying in the master view which I don't want to. I want to display one cell in my master view and two cells in the detail view . Here is my code

MYObject.h
    @interface MasDetailApp : NSObject

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *monthentered;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *monthsEnteredSoFar;
@end;
```

MasterView.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MYTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MYTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //use for loop to get all the data using one instance of nsobject


    _dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i=0; i<list.count; i=i+2) {

             MYObject *data1=[MyObject new];            //everytime loop starts creates a new instance of nsobject class

    //here the array "list" contains the data entered by the user        

            data1.name=[list objectAtIndex:i];
            data1.monthentered=[list objectAtIndex:i+1];
            data1.monthsEnteredSoFar=[list objectAtIndex:i+1];

           [_dataArray addObject:data1];

    }


    MyObject *firstData=[MyObject new];
    firstData= _dataArray[indexPath.row];

    cell.Name.text=firstData.name;
    cell.monthentered.text=firstData.monthentered;

    return cell;


}
```

DetailView.m

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MYDetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MYDetailTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //use for loop to get all the data using one instance of nsobject



    MyObject *firstData=[MyObject new];

    cell.Name.text=firstData.name;
    cell.monthenteredSoFar.text=firstData.monthentered;

    return cell;


}
```

Here I am getting the two rows in my Master view . 
Why I am not able to display two cells in my detail view. Can anyone help me in this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with `[MyObject new]` creates a new object in your detail view.  It can't give you the information that you stored into a different `MyObject`.

Comment: so,do i need to use two objects to display two cells in my detail view?